# extract file path right before jar

Tags: java, jar, filepath

Lets say you are using any kind of fileIO,

```
public class example{

    public Example(){
    File file = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());

    //file IO process ....
    }
}
```

by using `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` you'll get the full path with the "example.jar".
so, how can you get that file location but without the "example.jar" ?

(so actually the folder where the jar is located but not the link to the jar itself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
file.getParentFile()
```

See [`File#getParentFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29)

Comment: somehow, this works while running it from within the IDE, but once you try it as ajar, it doesn't ....

Answer (score -1):

You can use split with a delimiter, in your case the slash "/"
This will return an array and you need all the elements of the array, except the array.length-1 (last element)

Comment: This is a horrible solution especially as on some file systems file names can contain `/`.